# Problem with "check" notation and "bold mathcal" font

Tags: bold, accents, mathcal

I am trying to use the `\check` notation for `\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}`, but it does not appear in the right place; please see below for a minimal code and comparison with ordinary `A` and ordinary `\mathcal{A}`. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\check{A}\\
\check{\mathbf A}\\
\check{\mathcal A}\\
\boldsymbol{\check{\mathcal{A}}}\\ 
\check{\boldsymbol{\mathcal A}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you want `\boldsymbol{\check{\mathcal{A}}}` instead?

Comment: Thanks. It works, but it makes the "check" symbol also bold. I prefer not to  have the check symbol in bold.

Answer (score 4):

For automatic correct positioning, you should define a new math alphabet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\check{A}\\
\check{\mathbf{A}}\\
\check{\mathcal{A}}\\
\check{\mathbcal{A}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain why it's necessary to define the new alphabet?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Because the `\boldsymbol` way creates a subformula and in this case TeX puts the accent centered over the subformula. It's the same as `\check{abcdef}`.

Comment: I see. Thank you. You already had my +1 before the explanation :-)